# How does r.lake in GRASS work?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, lakes

I want to create a raster file with only the lake data with the r.lake tool. The data should only cover the lake that is red in the picture. [image: Lake area]

The inputs required for l.lake are:

- Raster file with elevations
- Water level
- Seed point coordinates

However, I have two problems:

1. When I introduce the water level of the lake (highest elevation point of the lake, 180 m) then the file created covers all the surface that is below 180 m. (As in the picture, [image]). But how do I do it if I only want a specific area?
2. What is the meaning of Seed point coordinates? Is it the maximum height of the lake?

I guess that if I get the correct answer of those questions, I will be able to create a raster file with only the lake data.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you correctly understood, `r.lake` calculates the depth between the your chosen water elevation and the ground, for all pixels that are below the elevation of that water level, and contiguous with the seed point.
2. The seed point just gives the algorithm a place to start. It expands out from that point to all connected pixels that are below the given water height.

From your image, it looks like there is a road/dam at the NW corner of the lake. So your elevation raster must include that dam if you want `r.lake` to "stop" there.